# Is it possible to determine which widget loads first on page?

Tags: magento2, image

When loading the homepage of my Magento 2 store it happens that the 2nd element is loading faster than the 1st element.

The 1st element is a slider widget and the 2nd a image html widget.

Is there a possibility to wait with loading the second (and following) element(s) before the first one is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify 'Sort order' of each widget. Widgets in same container will load according to their sort order.

Comment: I have this set already, but it happens that the second elements loads faster than the first element. So for 1 second you see the second element appearing first, then the first element loads on top of it.